# Blazor: How to pass very long string from JS to C#?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-jsinterop

I have a Blazor Component Library.
In the library my js code generates a huge string which is about 160 000 characters. Simplified JS below (actualy this is base64 string)

```
export function showPrompt(message): Uint8Array {
    alert(message);
    let str = "";
    for(let i = 0; i < 164232; i++)
        str += "A";
    return new TextEncoder().encode(str);
}
```

My C# code is:

```
async void CallJS() {
    string? str = null;
    IJSStreamReference? jsStream = await Prompt("After you will press ok, long string will be generated");
    if (jsStream != null) {
        using Stream referenceStream = await jsStream.OpenReadStreamAsync();
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[referenceStream.Length];
        int byteArrayCount = await referenceStream.ReadAsync(byteArray);
        str =  System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(byteArray, 0, byteArrayCount);
    }
    length = str?.Length ?? 0;
}
```

When I use this component in Blazor Server App, C# gets only 32 thousands chars. As I understand this is due to Signal-R limitation. I've found this topic: [Pass large JS blob to Blazor byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68371516/pass-large-js-blob-to-blazor-byte) and tried the  solution, but even with the code below, c# receives only 50 000 characters.

```
  services.AddSignalR(o => {
    o.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
    o.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = long.MaxValue;
  });
```

How to pass a huge string from JS to C# in Blazor?

Comment: Why not chunk the string and send it in batches? Or (if possible) generate the string in Blazor code so that it doesn't need to be sent over interop?

Comment: It seems to chunk is a good decision. I'll try it. I need to know actual Signal-R message size to understand the chunk size.

Comment: @EugeneMaksimov: You can set _MaximumReceiveMessageSize_ to _null_, to make it unlimited.

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal, it seems it doesn't work in blazor:  I set this parameter to null and I've managed to receive only about 50 000 symbols.

https://github.com/EugeniyMaksimov/PassLongStringFromJSToCSinBlazor

Comment: @EugeneMaksimov: "I've managed to receive only about 50 000 symbols". It is because you are restricting the number of bytes to be decoded from a long content. It should be `System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(byteArray)` to read all incoming content instead of `System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(byteArray, 0, byteArrayCount)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have managed to solve this problem only by chanking the message:

TS:
//Type Script Code:

```
let str = "";

//generate large string
export function exportImageAndGetBase64Length(message): number {
    alert(message);
    for(let i = 0; i < 164232; i++)
        str += "A";
    return str.length;
}

//get part of the generated string
export function getChunk(startIndex, endIndex): string {
    return str.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
}

//finish transition and clean up the string 
export function ClearBuffer() {
    str = "";
}
```

Razor

```
inject Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions<Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.HubOptions> Options
```

C#:

```
async void GetLongStringFromJS() {
    int fileLength = await module.InvokeAsync<int>("exportImageAndGetBase64Length", "long string of 164232 will be generated and send to c#");

    HubOptions a = Options.Value;
    int maximumSingnalRMessageSize = (a.MaximumReceiveMessageSize == null || a.MaximumReceiveMessageSize > 32768) ? 32768 : (int)a.MaximumReceiveMessageSize;

    int chunkLength = (int)maximumSingnalRMessageSize / sizeof(char);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int startIndex = 0, endIndex = chunkLength; startIndex <= fileLength; startIndex += chunkLength, endIndex += chunkLength) {
        if (endIndex > fileLength + 1)
            endIndex = fileLength + 1;
        string chunk = await module.InvokeAsync<string>("getChunk", startIndex, endIndex);
        sb.Append(chunk);
    }
    length = sb.Length; //do somthing with your string
    await module.InvokeVoidAsync("ClearBuffer");
    this.StateHasChanged();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped me a lot. This post should be updated since `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR` is marked as deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

We hit the same problem - I think the problem is, that SignalR is chunking the message when using `IJSStreamReference` if it is too big. When you call `await referenceStream.ReadAsync(byteArray);` there is a posibillity that the Message isn't completely transfered yet.

Try copying the `referenceStream` to an `MemoryStream` and call .ToArray() on it.

```
async void CallJS() {
    string? str = null;
    IJSStreamReference? jsStream = await Prompt("After you will press ok, long string will be generated");
    if (jsStream != null) {
        await using Stream referenceStream = await jsStream.OpenReadStreamAsync();
        using var memStream = new MemoryStream();
        await referenceStream.CopyToAsync(memStream);
        var byteArray = memStream.ToArray();
        str =  System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(byteArray);
    }
    length = str?.Length ?? 0;
}
```

Or maybe even better, use an `StreamReader`:

```
async void CallJS() {
    string? str = null;
    IJSStreamReference? jsStream = await Prompt("After you will press ok, long string will be generated");
    if (jsStream != null) {
        await using Stream referenceStream = await jsStream.OpenReadStreamAsync();
        using var sr = new StreamReader(referenceStream);
        var str = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
    }
    length = str?.Length ?? 0;
}
```

If it still doesn't work, take a look at the `maxAllowedSize` Parameter of the `OpenReadStreamAsync` Method